# Importing prices csv is taking a long time

Tags: magento-2.1, price, import, csv, reindex

In Magento 2, there are roughly 115,000 products in the store.  There are 7 customer groups.  When importing prices via csv, the batch upload slowly imports the price but eventually crawls to a stop.  I've checked all error logs in my server, can't find any failure notices in magento logs, or any other server logs.  No email is sent.

More details on the setup:

- RHEL 7
- PHP 7
- Apache
- MySQL
- Magento 2.1 EE

How I setup up the import is through a scheduled task, and hitting 'run'.  I've tried batches of 50000, 10000, 5000, 1000.  All have the same effect.  When uploading products, customers, and availability - Magento had no issue with big bulk uploading.

Another symptom I may be seeing is bin/magento indexer:reindex takes no more than :30 seconds for each category, except for Prices and EAV.   It takes over 3 minutes each.  Currently there only 3000 prices in the database, so 3 minutes to reindex seems like a lot.

Has anyone come across this? Any suggested fixes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of deep diving in the magento code, discovered a config.xml limits the size of a bulk import.

This file can be found:
`/vendor/magento/module-import-export/etc/config.xml`

I then dialed in the numbers to a setting optimal for our code pushes.  Building a module for this override is the next step of course, but figured out the cause.

Answer (score 2):

Magento 2.x even though it's "*supposed to be faster than Magento 1.x*", the stack has doubled in size going from ~40 PHP files per request to ~80 PHP files to fulfill a single request, with the inclusion of vendors/composer.  Keep this in mind if you are seeing a lot of disk I/O when locating bottlenecks.

**However most of the bottleneck will likely be at the MySQL level:**

- **Disable** any unnecessary `indexing` & `cron` jobs or shut down all other services that are not needed during the import processes.
- Make sure to use **MySQL 5.7**. (Percona has a very nice InnoDB engine/tools)
- Bump up its `max_allowed_packet` that is larger than the default, 16MB
- Optimize to handle the large amounts of data you are putting in quickly since non-production fail-safe mechanisms aren't needed.
- `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit` to the value `2` in your `my.cnf` config file to [avoid over cautious writings](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit) while in a non production time frame.
- Be sure to use **PHP7** & **OPCache** configured properly per environment need. Use https://github.com/rlerdorf/opcache-status to monitor OPCache stats.
- Utilize tools such as: `htop`, `mytop`, `iotop`, `sysdig` and the best weapon of choice is: `strace`, and while in htop "s" keyboard shortcut on the highlighted process will basically run `strace` with the parameter of the processes ID highlighted. Or just `ps waux | grep mysql` and locate the id of the process and `strace <PID>`.

For the slow indexing process: Recreate the MySQL triggers for the indexer, and enable the Scheduled indexing process (make sure cron is setup/enabled)

`php bin/magento index:trigger:recreate -vvv`

The indexer in Magento 2 relies **heavily** on the **MySQL trigger** feature to speed up indexing, along with changelogs & the cron jobs keeping the indexer updated with deltas, instead of ignoring whats changed when doing a full reindex.

Details: [Magento 2.1 on MySQL](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/mysql.html).

> **Below are some main Magento2 MySQL Recommeded Configurations.**
>
> 1. The Magento application requires MySQL 5.6.x.
> 2. Magento versions 2.1.2 and later are compatible with MySQL 5.7.x.
> 3. Magento uses MySQL database triggers to improve database access
>    during reindexing.
> 4. If you expect to import large numbers of products into Magento, you
>    can increase the value for max_allowed_packet that is larger than
>    the default, 16MB.
> 5. MariaDB and Percona are compatible with Magento because we support
>    MySQL 5.6 APIs.

- source: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/151268/69

---

### EDIT

Additional MySQL Settings regarding large import of data:

- https://gist.github.com/molotovbliss/27919f6af96a88c827f50d529f6de59c
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83125/mysql-any-way-to-import-a-huge-32-gb-sql-dump-faster

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a script similar today that allowed one of my clients to import there prices and stock and found that i was needing to reindex the data after roughly 500 records it had no issue but when i tried to import more it had issues id suggest doing 500 first if that works for you then id consider continuing

Comment: Still had that issue.  Hacked magento's core to get this fixed, not the best way to go about it.  I'll post my findings if another answer doesn't present itself.

Comment: Never mess with the core either extend or overwrite in your own extension never modify magentos core files