# Magento 2 Price of configurable is zero on store front

Tags: magento2, csv, magento2.2.9

We make an import of CSV with products programmatically and getting prices $0.00 on the storefront for the first time. After some minutes it's getting normal. I am using Magento 2.2.9 Community Edition. I believe it's some issue with reindex or something..there are many products and we can't make full reindex after each import.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your saying that you don't have price import problem but rather the time it takes for the price to effectively show up on the frontend.

Assuming this scenario, i'll list down the following steps which could help this process faster.

**Below are some main Magento2 MySQL Recommeded Configurations.**

1. The Magento application requires MySQL 5.6.x.
2. Magention versions 2.1.2 and later are compatible with MySQL 5.7.x.
3. Magento uses MySQL database triggers to improve database access
   during reindexing.
4. If you expect to import large numbers of products into Magento, you
   can increase the value for max_allowed_packet that is larger than
   the default, 16MB.
5. MariaDB and Percona are compatible with Magento because we support
   MySQL 5.6 APIs.

> For more details Refer this devdocs link -
>   http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/mysql.html
>
> Devdocs has listed all the recommended configuration.

- source: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/151268/69

The indexer in Magento 2 relies heavily on the MySQL trigger feature to speed up indexing, this along with change logs & the cron jobs keeping the indexer updated with deltas, instead of ignoring whats changed when doing a full reindex.

**You can remove cron by running:**

> php bin/magento cron:remove

It will only remove cron tasks from crontab but not the exact cron codes/files.

**If you wish to run the cron jobs again:**

> php bin/magento cron:run

Comment: Unfortunately, that answer can't help me. We have full requirements, we're on well-known Magento hosting right now. Also, we can't run full reindex after each incoming chunk of products - it destroys performance at all.