# How to optimize MariaDB for best Magento 2 performance and Increase indexing speed?

Tags: magento2, mariadb

I working on Magento2.4.6 with 7 stores and more than 90 000 products.

We used MariaDB as Database with 32GB of RAM.

What is the best DB configurations (parameters) recommanded to increase the performance.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you already saw, but it's worth having a look at this article https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/151222/magento2-mysql-recommeded-configurations, though it might be a bit out-dated, but regarding the database configuration it should still be relevant.

Comment: Hello @giangvdm, thank you for your replay. I will check this post and try to adjust mon DB configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have MariaDB 10.11.

Try the following:

```
skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 100M
table_open_cache = 400
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
query_cache_size = 100M
log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1
skip-networking
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 15G
innodb_log_file_size = 2G
optimizer_switch=rowid_filter=off
optimizer_use_condition_selectivity=1
```